# Expressing the area of a square as a function of its perimeter

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

The text is asking us to state the area A of a square as a function of the perimeter p.

If x = the length of a side of a square then the area A of the square = $x^2$

The perimeter $p = 4x$.

The solution is $\frac{p^2}{16}$

I see why the solution is what it is, but I'm struggling to understand how to derive the solution algebraically.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perimeter $p = 4x \iff x = \frac{p}{4} $. Hence

Area $a = x^2 = \left( \frac{p}{4} \right)^2 = \frac{p^2}{16} $

Comment: Ugh...so obvious in retrospect. Thank you!

Comment: you are welcome Nick.